# How to configure VS Code's CMake Tools Extension for GCC and MSYS Makefiles on Windows?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code, msys2

This question is about the *CMake Tools* extension for *VS Code*. The operation system is Windows 10.

The extension correctly found GCC, which I can verify by having a look at the `%LocalAppData%/CMakeTools/cmake-tools-kits.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "GCC 10.3.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32",
  "compilers": {
    "C": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe",
    "CXX": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe"
  }
}
```

I tried to configure through the respective VS Code command and got an error:

```
[rollbar] Unhandled exception: Unhandled Promise rejection: configure Error: No usable generator found. {}
```

Then I added the respective setting to my local settings `.vscode/settings.json`.

```json
{ "cmake.generator": "MSYS Makefiles" }
```

I got the following output:

```
[proc] Executing command: "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -H<path to project root> -B<path to build directory> -G "MSYS Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
[cmake] CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
[cmake] CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program. 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So I extended my local settings.

```json
{
  "cmake.generator": "MSYS Makefiles",
  "cmake.environment": {
    "CMAKE_AR": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/ar.exe",
    "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe"
  }
}
```

Got the same output as before. I also tried setting these variables in the `CMakeLists.txt` and as system environment variables.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Variable [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) is a **CMake variable**, not an **environment** one. (The variable is not listed among [environment variables affecting on CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html)). So, for set this variable you need to use "cmake.configureSettings" instead of  "cmake.environment".

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's it. Thank you. I got confused with environment and CMake variables. Why didn't you post it as an answer, though?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old request, but I've recently been suffering from this issue.

The trick I found (with the current version of MSYS2 on Windows), was to install the cmake version of mingw64.

With command:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
```

NOTE: This assumes that pacman is defined in your path, otherwise you will need to prefix the pacman with the path.

Then install Ninja:

```
pacman -S ninja
```

You shouldn't need to define the configuration in VSCode settings, it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

From the command from @Tsyvarev I was able to solve a similar issue for my setup, so I'll might as well post a answer for the next person.

I'm using UCRT64 environment instead of MINGW64, since this is the recommended MSYS2 environment. For OP's question change `ucrt64` to `mingw64`.

Some programs (git for Windows) might ship MINGW64 binaries. If you encounter issues try to set the `PATH` variable to exclude those directories.
If CMake can't find some standard libraries (e.g. openblas) try to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

My final `settings.json` looks something like this:

```json
{
  "cmake.cmakePath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cmake.exe",
  "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_AR": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/ar.exe",
    "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe",
    "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "C:/msys64/ucrt64"
  },
  "cmake.environment": {
    "PATH": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin;C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin;${env:PATH}"
  },
  "cmake.generator": "MSYS Makefiles",
  [...]
}
```